# Call a function from another cell in iPython

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

In a cell I have

```
  def function():
        stuff
```

In a cell below the previously mentioned cell, I call

```
   function()
```

The error I get is:

```
   name 'function' is not defined.
```

How do I call a function in another cell in iPython?

Comment: did you press "Run Cell" button on the cell which the `function` is defined?, the cell is not automatically executed when the notebook is displayed.  you have to manually run the cell.

Comment: you also can choose [Cell] -> [Run All] on the menubar to run all cells.

Answer (score 9):

Run the cell in which you defined the function first, then run the cell you call it from. If you make any changes to the function later, run that cell again for the changes to take effect, otherwise your calls will run the un-changed function.

or, as @ymonad pointed out, run all cells each time. it takes care of the trouble as long as function definition comes before any point it is called upon.

Comment: This does not work. I run the cell but it still is not avilable in subsequent cells.

Comment: @LennartRolland, share a sample ipynb file and i take a look. might be another error lurking somewhere

Comment: the error was on my side. After restarting kernel all was fine